# Implement F# interface via tacit programming

Tags: f#, functional-programming, first-class-functions, tacit-programming

An idea from [tacit programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tacit_programming) is to not apply arguments to functions if it can be avoided.

Why doesn't F# allow this to compile if functions are first class members?

```
type IAdder =
    interface
    abstract member Add : int -> int -> int
end

type Adder =
    interface IAdder with
        member this.Add x y = x + y

type AdderWithInnerAdder(adder:IAdder) =
    interface IAdder with
        member this.Add = adder.Add
```

I get the compilation error...

> No abstract property was found that corresponds to this override

I feel that this should compile. `adder.Add` clearly implements `IAdder.Add` and should be acceptable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't assign interface members as if they were functions. Interfaces don't work like that. You have to specify the parameters:

```
    member this.Add x y = adder.Add x y
```

But interfaces are generally bleh. They're only good for passing generic functions without losing genericity. When functions are non-generic, interfaces are strictly inferior.

If you were willing to go with a more functional approach instead, life would get easy fast:

```
type Adder = { Add: int -> int -> int }
let adder() = { Add = fun x y -> x + y }
let adderWithInnerAdder adder = { Add = adder.Add }
```

Comment: I like that there is a more functional way to approach this. The constraint is I have to interop with code written in C#. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @t3dodson If you need to interop with C# then curried args should probably be avoided in your interfaces too.  Working with `FSharpFunc`s in C# code is not going to make for an idiomatic experience.

Comment: @TheInnerLight, They only look curried from F# side. Member functions and let-bound functions are compiled to normal methods regardless of currying.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin what do you mean "let-bound function" can you link documentation about how this works on the C# side?

Comment: Let-bound functions are functions defined with `let`, for example `let f x y = x + y`. I don't have a link to any documentation on how stuff is compiled. You can easily check yourself with ILSpy.